# What is the difference between JSON and PSON (protocol JSON)?

Tags: json

I've recently heard of PSON, and I hear that its similar to JSON. that is is different in how the objects are encoded. But how are they different? More specifically, how are they different when used for serializing and deserializing data?

Comment: Appears the difference is only the encoding of the json string. Google mentions `PSON is a variant of JSON that puppet uses for serializing data to transmit across the network or store on disk. Whereas JSON requires that the serialized form is valid unicode (usually UTF-8), PSON is 8-bit ASCII, which allows it to represent arbitrary byte sequences in strings.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSON does not differ from JSON in its representation of objects, arrays, numbers, booleans, and null values. PSON does serialize strings differently from JSON.

A PSON string is a sequence of 8-bit ASCII encoded data. It must start and end with “ (ASCII 0x22) characters. Between these characters it may contain any byte sequence.

PSON combines the best of JSON, BJSON, ProtoBuf and a bit of ZIP to achieve a superior small footprint on the network level. Basic constants and small integer values are efficiently encoded as a single byte. Other integer values are always encoded as variable length integers. Additionally it comes with progressive and static dictionaries to reduce data redundancy to a minimum.

1. 246 single byte values
2. Base 128 variable length integers (varints) as in protobuf
3. 32 bit floats instead of 64 bit doubles if possible without information loss
4. Progressive and static dictionaries
5. Raw binary data support
6. Long support

Whereas JSON requires that the serialized form is valid unicode (usually UTF-8)

you can decode a PSON with JSON Parsers